# 2.3.1 not able to show products with "out of stock" with new MSI

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I recently updated Magento from 2.2.3 to 2.3.1

I´ve got a product which has 0 stock and is set to "out of stock" but the customer is able to buy it. (Setting is set to "show out of stock products")

Versions before we set the product to "Out of stock" and we could search and viewed that product, but could not put it into the cart.
Now, with the new Inventory Module from Magento, I´m just able to deactivate the product, which is not a good way for the search engine.

I also disabled all inventory modules but that leads to a problem showing categories with elastic-suite-extension.

How can I restore the old behavior so a customer can see my "out of stock"-product without putting it into the cart?
Someone a suggestion?

Best Regards
Logic

Comment: check (set) CATALOG=>Inventory=>Product Stock Options=>Backorders => No Backorders